# How to record a log message when saving a Commerce Order via Drupal EntityWrapper?

Tags: 7, commerce, entities

I'm modifying a set of orders programmatically and want to record a log message when doing so.

Is there an existing method to add a revision and log when doing so?

```
$order_id = 800;
$order = commerce_order_load($order_id);
$order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
$order_wrapper->uid->set(1);
$order_wrapper->mail->set('test@example.com');
// $order_wrapper->log->set('Changed order owner and mail');
// $order_wrapper->revision->set(true);
$order_wrapper->save();
```

Currently if I try `$order_wrapper->log->set('x');` I see *EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property log.*, but I believe this is a property of the order (based on getPropertyInfo() etc).

Does Commerce Order + Entity Metadata Wrappers have support for creating a new revision on save, or recording an order log message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to set the `revision` and `log` properties on the default order object, instead of the wrapper.

e.g:

```
$order_id = 800;
$order = commerce_order_load($order_id);
$order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
$order_wrapper->uid->set(1);
$order_wrapper->mail->set('test@example.com');
// Set revision details on order object
$order->revision = TRUE;
$order->log = t('Changed order owner and mail');
$order_wrapper->save();
```

As the order object is passed by reference, from memory the revision log info can be set that way.

Comment: Seems you're right! I'd tried this earlier (amongst other things!) and thought it hadn't worked, but it does. Thanks so much.

Comment: You’re welcome, all the best with the project.